# How to redirect to a Facebook fanpage with ID of fanpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have the ID of a facebook fanpage, and only the ID. Which link I have to build to redirect to this fanpage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out Page Tab URL from Page ID and application ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585234/find-out-page-tab-url-from-page-id-and-application-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you query the graph using the object id (user, page..group...etc):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305
{
   "id": "40796308305",
   "name": "Coca-Cola",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/157930_40796308305_262497158_s.jpg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
   "likes": 40005128,
   "category": "Food/beverages",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
   "username": "coca-cola",
   "founded": "1886",
   "description": "Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
   "about": "The Coca-Cola Facebook Page is a collection of your stories showing how people from around the world have helped make Coke into what it is today.",
   "location": {
      "latitude": -33.816989983333,
      "longitude": 150.84844081667
   },
   "can_post": true,
   "checkins": 78,
   "talking_about_count": 583000
}
```

Querying Facebook directly would also redirect to the "*object*" page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/40796308305 --> https://www.facebook.com/cocacola  
https://www.facebook.com/579187142  --> https://www.facebook.com/ifaour
```

Yet this is **not** an official way. So I'm not sure if this could stop working in the future.

Comment: Yep, this may stop working at any time and there is downside of using it anyway since you cannot redirect that way to Page tabs or pass any arguments...

Comment: of course you can't redirect to page tabs..etc but this is really not an issue, because if the app is to be used on multiple pages...the dev should query the page id returned when adding the tab and then save the page `link` along with the id.

Comment: I meant you can't direct to tab in a page like `http://facebook.com/9445547199?sk=notes` (but this one works `http://facebook.com/pages/-/9445547199?sk=notes`)

Comment: but again, this also may stop working because you are missing the page title. Well, at least you can link to tabs now :)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want link that will bring you to the fanpage itself you may use:

```
http://facebook.com/ANY_FACEBOOK_ID
```

It'll work for any Facebook ID, no matter page, user, application

**Update:**
As discussed in comments to other answer there is a some downsides to the link described above:

- This is in no way official way and it's not documented, so it may just stop working without any notice...
- Any arguments passed to this link are removed on redirection to Page. (Using `http://facebook.com/PAGEID?sk=notes` will not redirect to Notes application)

So if you need to direct users not only to the page itself but to application on a Page you may use links like:

```
http://facebook.com/pages/-/PAGEID?sk=app_APPID
```