# Find out Page Tab URL from Page ID and application ID

Tags: facebook, url

I'm building a Facebook app that can be installed on Pages (a Page Tab app), and would like to redirect my users to their Page Tabs, knowing only the app ID, and the Page ID.

Let's say for example that my app is installed on this page:
`http://www.facebook.com/coldplay` whose ID is `15253175252`, and my app ID is `174314562666399`.

I know I can access the Page using only its numerical ID: `http://facebook.com/15253175252` redirects to the Coldplay page.

And I can access the Page Tab with this URL: `http://www.facebook.com/coldplay/app_174314562666399`. **Is there a way to get Facebook to redirect me to this Page Tab using only the Page ID and app ID?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to a Facebook fanpage with ID of fanpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489222/how-to-redirect-to-a-facebook-fanpage-with-id-of-fanpage)

Comment: But Juicy Scripter is exactly the same answer as the below?!

Comment: My question is specifically about Page **Tabs**.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can pass in the APP ID with the sk=app_app_id parameter, but you'll lose it when using the Page ID instead of the Pagename - it's not redirected along with the request.

There's a workaround I've used before though: you'll need to write a FB redirect proof URL from the information you have.

So:

http://facebook.com/pages/-/15253175252?sk=app_174314562666399

That is:

http://facebook.com/pages/-/[page_id]?sk=app_[app_id]

Comment: good stuff man, I've been looking for this for  along time! :)

Comment: @PepeGombos really glad this is still coming in handy - if only Facebook documentation had these kind of hints easily accessible.

Comment: Wow, is this documented anywhere?  The previous URL format that I had been applying stopped working recently in certain scenarios, but this solution works all of the time.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika I've not seen it documented ever, but it does seem to keep on working through various Facebook changes.

Comment: Well it seems like this url format is broken now.  :-(  I can't come up with a solid way of link to my application tab on a Facebook Page.  I'm not sure why Facebook doesn't provide this to us so that we can get rid of the guessing game.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering may be a temporary bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/408615369335909/

Comment: @JohnnyOshika Just came across this issue too, :/

Comment: Yes - seems they've broken it properly at the moment. Annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

Replacing my previous answer with this one, updated **2020-08-06**

#### Classic Facebook Design:

1. This works: `{page.link}?sk=app_{app.id}`
2. This works: `{page.link}/app/{app.id}`
3. This redirects correctly: `https://facebook.com/pages/-/{page.id}?sk=app_{app.id}`
4. This redirects correctly: `https://facebook.com/{page.id}?sk=app_{app.id}`
5. This redirects correctly: `https://facebook.com/{page.id}/app/{app.id}`

Of the many approaches above, I recommend 2 (for compatibility with New Facebook Design) and 5, as 5 seems to be the default approach for Facebook Pages that don't have vanity URLs defined yet. 3 should be avoided because some virus scanners (e.g. Norton 360) rejects it as a dangerous website.

#### New Facebook Design:

1. Does not work (loads the page default): `{page.link}?sk=app_{app.id}`
2. This works: `{page.link}/app/{app.id}`
3. Does not work (redirects to page default): `https://facebook.com/pages/-/{page.id}?sk=app_{app.id}`
4. Does not work (redirects to vanity URL and loads page default): `https://facebook.com/{page.id}?sk=app_{app.id}`
5. Should work, but there's currently a bug that redirects incorrectly and drops the AppID to `https://facebook.com/{page.id}/app/`: `https://facebook.com/{page.id}/app/{app.id}`. Bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/313625599658979/