# How do I get a Facebook page tab URL from with page tab app

Tags: facebook

I have a page tab application with a share button that invokes the Facebook feed dialog. I want the story link to point back to the page tab application. How can I find out the page tab  url from within the page tab app itself? I cannot use `top.location.href` because of cross-domain security issues, but I don't see how else the application itself can figure out the necessary url. Specifying the page tab app in a config setting is not an option - too fragile and prone to maintenence problems (i.e. publish from staging to prod without updating url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit roundabout, but it's fairly solid.

The `signed_request` will give you a `page_id`. You can then query the graph api for the `link` param on that Page ID. Combo that with `app_<APP_ID>` and you've got your URL.

eg - https://www.facebook.com/colmstestpage/app_120999667956026

https://www.facebook.com/colmstestpage/ comes from `http://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>?fields=link` and `/app_120999667956026` is consistent and you don't need to query for your `app_id`.

Comment: This is no longer reliable and breaks if the Page URL contains an ID (i.e. the Page hasn't secured a fully unique username).  As of 2015-11-03, the technique described here still works in all scenarios that I tested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9587363/188740